# Flash object is downloading instead showing

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, flash

I moved to new web hosting. Now I have some problems.
Every time I visit my website with any browser, my flash object (games, clocks, etc) are being downloaded instead showed in the page. I was searching in google something about that problem, but nothing...

Is there anything that i can do, to fix it? Something with `.htaccess`? I'm using `iframe` for loading the flash. Also i'm using `PHP` version 5.5 (on my old hosting i was on version 5.4).

Comment: Did you check if the problem is with browser support ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: Actually i didn't realize that the web hosting gave me more permissions, which reset my php version back to default 5.6. I set it again to 5.5, and everything is find :) Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the `Content-Type` headers? as far as i know `Content-Type` can be controlled through .htaccess using the AddType directive. In my case `AddType`

`AddType text/html .html`

Comment: and this should be in the main dir, or the flash dir?

Answer (score 0):

> *"I'm using `iframe` for loading the Flash."*

Nowadays browsers like Chrome do not directly load SWF (Flash) files.

It won't work if you **directly** point the address bar or the `iframe` **src** to an .`swf` file.

**Solution**:

Using `iframe`, you must load an `.html` file that itself embeds the `.swf` file.

So don't load in your `iframe` as: `http://www.mysite/someFlash.swf`... 
Instead you load as `http://www.mysite/someFlash.html` where the HTML file code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="http://www.mysite/someFlash.swf" width="800" height="600">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably i will make embed, but my point was, that in the old hosting it was working, here no :/

Answer (score 0):

maybe the server is not configure to recognize the 'swf' extension.

If this is the case you can ask the host to add the flash extension and mime type to the list in the server.

extension - mimetype

```
swf - application/x-shockwave-flash swf
```